# Try Catch in Java | Json still crashes

Tags: java, android, json, try-catch

```
                 try {
                          Log.e("getTrackerSettings | ", json);
                          trackerSettings = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeToken);
                      } catch ( IllegalStateException e) {
                          Log.e("getTrackerSettings inside catch | ", "");
                          e.printStackTrace();
                          trackerSettings = new TrackerSettings(1, "Hello", "73");
                      }
```

This code snippet will crash, and give the following:

```
E/getTrackerSettings inside try |: false
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sendiman.manager, PID: 13196
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 6 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
```

As you can see, this does no make sense. The entire function is inside a larger try catch( Exception e) as well.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the try catch. Your json seems to be invalid. What exactly did you think might throw a 'JsonSyntaxException' except for that?

Comment: better to solve the root of your problems, figure out how to correctly parse this json, then there's no need for this

Comment: You should catch the `JsonSyntaxException`, not the nested `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: and what is the problem ? You experiencing unexpected behavior then tell us about it

Comment: I am aware that the Json is invalid, that's why I put it in a TryCatch.
Is there a better way to check if the Json is valid?

Comment: you can look at the json. seeing as you are already logging it, that shouldn't pose a problem, should it?

Comment: Thing is: it is your application, your requirements. If silently ignoring invalid JSON is the preferred solution here ... then something like the above is totally fine: you try to acquire the information needed, it fails, so you default to something else. But as mentioned before: you would rather want to catch the JsonSyntaxException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromJson` method throws a `com.google.json.JsonSyntaxException`. It does not throw a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. You're catching the wrong thing.

The text highlights *why* the JSON is bad, and that IllegalStateException came up as part of parsing it. It's a causal relationship. Think of exceptions not as 'this specific thing went wrong', but as an alternate return value. The `fromJson` call returns *either* a T object (the thing you're trying to parse), *OR* a JsonSyntaxException, and that JsonSyntaxException object (exceptions are just objects) contains the details. You can query it by assigning it to a variable, and its toString also just prints the details. 'some inner parsing code threw an IllegalStateException' is the detail here.

It looks like you're attempting to parse the string `"true"` or `"false"` as json. It's not valid JSON, in the sense that all JSON has to be a JSON object in its outermost level.

Replace `catch (IllegalStateException)` with `catch (JsonSyntaxException)` instead.

Comment: This indeed solved the problem. However, the entire function was nested in a try catch ( Exception e), and it did not catch the crash. Why was that? Why did specifying the Exception work, but a general Exception throw?

Comment: Because `JsonSyntaxException` was thrown, not `IllegalStateException`. `catch (SomeExceptionType foo)` is triggered for any throwable whose type is `SomeExceptionType` or some subtype of it. (Exception types are just classes; you can have them `extend` things if you want. They must extend `Throwable`, but indirectly is okay (e.g. `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`, and `Exception` extends `Throwable` and that's fine).  `JsonSyntaxException` is _not_ a subtype of `IllegalStateException`, hence `catch (IllegalStateException)` isn't triggered for this.

Comment: `catch (Throwable t) {}` is a bad idea, but that will always trigger if anything is thrown anywhere in its try block. I can't stress how bad an idea that is. Generally `catch (Exception e) {}` is a slightly less bad idea (in that the only throwables that aren't also Exceptions are core issues like out of memory or corrupt JVM installations, and throwables-as-control-flow structures).

Answer (score 1):

luk2302 Answered in comments.

Catch (JsonSyntaxException e)did catch the crash.

Comment: you can accept your own answer if you want, or let luk create an answer - but definitely upvote his comment.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It still fail because you are trying to catch `IllegalStateException` and not `JsonSyntaxException`

From [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-) documentation the signature of `fromJson` is:

`public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException`

```
try {
     Log.e("getTrackerSettings | ", json);
     trackerSettings = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeToken);
} catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
     Log.e("getTrackerSettings inside catch | ", "");
     e.printStackTrace();
     trackerSettings = new TrackerSettings(1, "Hello", "73");
}
```